# pygame get event key code

Tags: python, pygame

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN or event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        print (event)
```

When I pressed arrow up this was the
output:

```
<Event(2-KeyDown {'unicode': '', 'key': 273, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 111})>
```

What is the syntax to access the dict? I want just to print the key `key` value from this dict. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

To get the value of the key that triggered the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event, just use `event.key` to get the value. Currently you're printing the `pygame.Event` object, but not the key of the event. Try the following:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN or event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        print(event.key)
```